# копирование данных скриптом google spreadsheet

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Не понимаю, как сделать так, чтобы данные с ячейки С2 и D2, при выполнении скрипта записывались в другую таблицу, или на другой лист этой таблицы. [image: Лист 1 где вводим данные]

Пример результата работы скрипта [image: Лист 2 с сохраненными данными]

Comment: А какая же логика? ТО есть на каком основании сначала в A45 - а потом в A34 ? Если нет знаний в данном языке - напишите программу на языке логики (что за чем следует и по каким условиям)

Comment: Знания есть. Минимальные.

Comment: Смысл такой: Допустим А1 = ID, B1 = ФИО, C1 = некие данные. Нужно при выполнении скрипта записать в другую таблицу "C1", по критерию "A1".

Comment: А1 допустим вводим вручную или импортирую.

Comment: Уже и вопрос поменялся)

Comment: Стал более конкретней

Comment: Гриша разводит сообщество на очередное 150 рублевое решение. Ну-ну, Гриша, давай.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Имя листа")
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("Ссылка на нужную книгу")
  var sheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName("Имя второго листа")

  var id = sheet.getRange("A2").getValue()
  var fio = sheet.getRange("B2").getValue()
  var city = sheet.getRange("C2").getValue()
  var street = sheet.getRange("D2").getValue()

  var arrIds = sheet2.getRange("A2:A6").getValues()

  for(var i = 0; i<arrIds.length; i++){
    if(id == arrIds[i][0]){
      sheet2.getRange(2+i, 2).setValue(fio)
      sheet2.getRange(2+i, 3).setValue(city)
      sheet2.getRange(2+i, 4).setValue(street)
      break
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77193/discussion-on-answer-by------google-spre).